# How to stop webcam running when navigated to another page in UWP application

Tags: camera, uwp, webcam

I have a camera feature in my UWP application, and one part of the feature is to actually check whether there is any camera device found connected. I developed the feature following this set of example: [CameraStarterKit](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit)

When I tested the codes on a machine without a webcam or camera, the message prompt will be shown. But I think that the codes that are checking whether there is a camera device is still running behind when I exit the page as the prompt is showing up when I minimize the application and open it up again.

Is there anyway I can stop the codes for checking whether there is a camera is connected when I navigate to another page?

Here is the codes for checking the if there is a camera connected:

```
private async Task InitializeCameraAsync()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("InitializeCameraAsync");

        if (_mediaCapture == null)
        {


            // Attempt to get the back camera if one is available, but use any camera device if not
            var cameraDevice = await FindCameraDeviceByPanelAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);

            if (cameraDevice == null)
            {
                this.LoadProgressRing.IsActive = false;
                this.LoadProgressStackPanel.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;

                MessageDialog cameraError = new MessageDialog("Connection Problem. No camera device found. Please kindly contacct the administrator.");
                UICommand YesBtn = new UICommand("Ok", delegate (IUICommand command)
                {
                    idleTimer.Stop();
                    var rootFrame = (Window.Current.Content as Frame);
                    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(HomePage));
                    rootFrame.BackStack.Clear();
                });
                cameraError.Commands.Add(YesBtn);
                await cameraError.ShowAsync();


                Debug.WriteLine("No camera device found!");
                return;
            }


            // Create MediaCapture and its settings
            _mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();


            var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = cameraDevice.Id };

            // Initialize MediaCapture
            try
            {
                await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
                _isInitialized = true;
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("The app was denied access to the camera");
            }

            // If initialization succeeded, start the preview
            if (_isInitialized)
            {
                // Figure out where the camera is located
                if (cameraDevice.EnclosureLocation == null || cameraDevice.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Unknown)
                {
                    // No information on the location of the camera, assume it's an external camera, not integrated on the device
                    _externalCamera = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Camera is fixed on the device
                    _externalCamera = false;

                    // Only mirror the preview if the camera is on the front panel
                    _mirroringPreview = (cameraDevice.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Front);
                }

                // Initialize rotationHelper
                _rotationHelper = new CameraRotationHelper(cameraDevice.EnclosureLocation);
                _rotationHelper.OrientationChanged += RotationHelper_OrientationChanged;

                await StartPreviewAsync();

                UpdateCaptureControls();


            }

            return;
        }

    }
```

**EDIT**

Codes for **SetUpBasedOnStateAsync()** method:

```
private async Task SetUpBasedOnStateAsync()
    {
        // Avoid reentrancy: Wait until nobody else is in this function.
        while (!_setupTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            await _setupTask;
        }

        // We want our UI to be active if
        // * We are the current active page.
        // * The window is visible.
        // * The app is not suspending.
        bool wantUIActive = _isActivePage && Window.Current.Visible && !_isSuspending;

        if (_isUIActive != wantUIActive)
        {
            _isUIActive = wantUIActive;

            Func<Task> setupAsync = async () =>
            {
                if (wantUIActive)
                {
                    await SetupUiAsync();
                    await InitializeCameraAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    await CleanupCameraAsync();
                    await CleanupUiAsync();
                }
            };
            _setupTask = setupAsync();
        }

        await _setupTask;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway I can stop the codes for checking whether there is a camera is connected when I navigate to another page?

When you navigate to another page, the [OnNavigatingFrom](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit/cs/MainPage.xaml.cs#L122) handler method would be called, you could see that `SetUpBasedOnStateAsync` method would be called in it. In this method, the `InitializeCameraAsync` method would be called. So, you just need to change some lines codes in `SetUpBasedOnStateAsync` method.

> But I think that the codes that are checking whether there is a camera device is still running behind when I exit the page as the prompt is showing up when I minimize the application and open it up again.

It's normal behavior. When you minimize and open your app,the code would go into this [if](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit/cs/MainPage.xaml.cs#L520) block. If you do not want this behavior. I suggest that you could create a new project instead of changing the official code sample. Because you would need to change many places.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! :) I have added the codes for SetUpBasedOnStateAsync method, how do I change the codes in them? Or what should I modify in the codes?

Comment: @thalassophile I didn't know why you said the code will check whether there's a camera when you navigate to another page. If I test the MS official code sample, when I navigate to other page, the code will clean up camera instead of detecting camera.

Comment: I have added a message dialog to prompt user that there is no camera device found if the system detected. I try on a desktop with no webcam connected and the message did pop up, I click on the command button and it went back to my HomePage... however, when I minimize my application and open it up again, the message dialog stating that there is no camera device found pops up again.

Comment: @thalassophile Please check my above reply. I'v updated it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice!:)  So I guess there isnt any easy way out... haha!